# Joining two very large csv files using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, join

I have two large files which I'd like to join based on certain similar columns. File1 is about 9.5Gb whereas file2 is about 1.5Gb in size. This is the code I used to join these files.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv(r"file1_path", dtype= str)
df2 = pd.read_csv(r"file2_path", dtype = str)
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = ['Date', 'ProductPartitionID', 'AdGroupID'], how = 'left')
df3=df3[['Date','AccountDescriptiveName','AdGroupID','AdGroupName','CampaignId','CampaignName','ExternalCustomerId', 'ProductGroup','ProductPartitionID', 'Cost','Impressions','Clicks','Conversions','ConversionValue', 'AllConversions','AllConversionValue','SearchAbsoluteTopImpressionShare', 'ShoppingID', 'SKU','CNT_DIST_SESSIONS','SUM_CM_ORDER_AMT','SUM_NEW_CUST_TODAY_IND', 'SUM_ORDER_CNT','SUM_PRODUCT_VIEW_CNT','SUM_REACTIVANT']]
df3.set_index('Date', inplace = True)
df3.to_csv('Shopping_aw_final.csv')
```

I'm executing this code using Jupyter Notebook. Since these files are so large, it's taking forever to do the job and my laptop is hanging because of this which stalls the process way too many times. I don't think it's possible to get through with the task using pandas in this way. Can anyone suggest any alternative methods I could use to get this done?

Comment: Whats your RAM? Have you explored `chunksize` parameter in `read_csv`? One way could be reading file2 entirely in memory and read file1 in chunks, process the chunks. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13059/merging-large-csv-files-in-pandas

Comment: My RAM is 16GB. I'm completely new to coding and python as such. Just started a week back. I haven't explored the chunksize parameter yet. I'll have a look and see how I can implement it. In case there's very little modification to be made to the code above after adding the chunksize, could you let me know what would be the change? If quite a lot needs to be changed, then I'll try working my way around myself anyway. Thanks! :)